# SWIFT- How to delete Collection View Cell if indexPatih is 0?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I'm new in swift and I need help with deleting colleciton view cell. In this code, if indexPath is 0, i have error with deleting that cell.

```
 @IBAction func deleteItem(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if let selectedCells = tablesCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems{
        let items = selectedCells.map {$0.item}.sorted().reversed()
        

        for item in items {
            tables.remove(at: item)
            let tableNo: TableModel
            tableNo = tables[item-1]  //Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
            
            refTables = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!).child("tables")
            refTables.child(tableNo.id!).removeValue { error,arg  in
               if error != nil {
                   print("error \(error)")
               }
             }
            
        }
      
        tablesCollectionView.deleteItems(at: selectedCells)
        deleteButton.isEnabled = false
    }
    
}
```

I have this message "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" when I try to delete the cell with 0 indexPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
tables.remove(at: item)
```

Is dangerous inside a `for` loop , as while you delete from array it's size changes which make old indices goes wrong

You need

```
var toDeleteIds = [String]()
for item in items {
  let tableNo = tables[item]  
  toDeleteIds.append(tableNo.id!)
  refTables =  Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!).child("tables")
  refTables.child(tableNo.id!).removeValue { error,arg  in
    if error != nil {
      print("error \(error)")
    }
  } 
} 
tables.removeAll { toDeleteIds.contains($0.id) }
```

Comment: I try this but now the error is "Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Int'" on line toDeleteIds.append(tableNo.id) and   tables.removeAll {toDeleteIds.contains($0)}

Comment: ok try edit....

Comment: Oh, now again same message on this linelet tableNo = tables[item-1] "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

Comment: why there is `-1` can you remove it ?

Comment: I forgot, now is working. Thank you so much! :)